# How do I implement a Browse button functionality through Qt

Tags: c++, qt, button

I am doing as much as I can with Qt Designer and some understanding of Slots-Signals and Widget interface without jumping into UI related code.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with a Qt plugin to create the application. In my actual application (in C++) for "doing" something else, I have let's say a function that needs path to 2 files. Up until now I have hard-coded it manually like:

```
String s1("The path");
```

I want to add a GUI for **being able to click a Browse button and locate the file and retrieve its location to `s1` String in my application's function.**

With this simple aim, I needed something of a simple window with a **Browse button** for both the files, and an area to show the loaded resource (if an image) if that's possible, though not absolutely necessary.

And this is why I took up Qt to achieve something like this. I have been able to do basic design and slot-signal custom calls. But I have no idea, how to further with the Browse Button aim of mine.

Is there any pre-built functionality/code/facility of any sort of achieving it in a shortcut or maybe an idea of actually doing it in Qt (which I am all for)?

Comment: So you needed a file dialog and you didn't think to search the docs for "file dialog" (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/search-results.html?q=file%20dialog)? Please show some research effort next time.

Comment: @cmannett85 :  I am not in general a GUI designer, haven't worked in it ever before. So, the terminology "file dialog" (believe me when I say this) really isn't familiar to me. I swear.

Comment: Qt Assistant has a search bar (and feels more usable than the new online docs to me). The second result for "browse button" is the [Find Files Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-dialogs-findfiles-example.html).

Comment: @Leiaz : That is a highly helpful comment. TY(+1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be easily done with [`QFileDialog::getOpenFileName`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName). In the slot connected to your "Browse" button, do something like this:

```
QString s1 =
    QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open a file", "directoryToOpen",
        "Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg);;Text files (*.txt);;XML files (*.xml)");
```

Read the documentation carefully, everything's there. You might also want to look at other static functions of [`QFileDialog`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html) like [`QFileDialog::getSaveFileName`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getSaveFileName) that you might need in the future.

Comment: And I say it again, Thank You for the answer and advice.

Comment: @pulp_fiction better check the answer as correct one :)